# Is there really something new happening in modern world, except from science and technology?

Tags: history-of-philosophy

It's said that history repeats itself. It seems to me though in every field (apart from science and technology) most events are reoccurring, repeating themselves. Especially in political and social, religious matters. It seems to me that some certain events are happening again & again since ancient times. The only difference is that they are happening in modern day era. What I really mean is that the social, political, religious issues or matters remained same over time, with little difference. e.g. Political actions, religious views towards each other. Etc.

Comment: To touch on a thoroughly modern and novel but solely social and political issue: civil rights, first extended to women, then to people of all races and creeds, and most recently to people of all sexual orientations. Even more currently, society is learning to accept that the idea of gender is more than binary. None of these ideas had any currency in almost any place or time in the past; in fact, most of them were explicitly thought absurd, dangerous, or appalling. So there is yet something new under the sun.

Comment: The sexual orientation bit and the gender bit are not new in the West  (Cf. http://www.amazon.com/Homosexuality-Greece-Rome-Sourcebook-Documents/dp/0520234308 ) -- though I guess the language has changed somewhat (but not entirely). Nor is equal treatment. / The notion of rights on the other hand might be new depending on what it is taken to mean.

Comment: The gender issues are not new in modern times ,there were ' GANDHRVAS 'people who were of third gender. But were having social status , in hindu mythology since ancient times.  And my point is of historical events, situations  repeating over time again and again.Well thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my point of view. In every field known to man, there comes a time where there is a saturation. Then somebody comes along and redraws the whole map leading to a totally different world view. This has been happening all this while. Maybe that is the true nature of progress, I'm not sure. But we have been making a steady climb towards betterment in all such fields. And also I dare to speculate that, the higher we climb, the longer it gets to change things all together, as the field itself gets better and better. Sometimes new fields emerge, sometimes old well established fields merge to become one. Maybe there are infinite number of fields but maybe there's just one. The bottomline is, progress is inevitable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we live in large societies where on a day to day basis we meet and interact with strangers (usually peacefully).  Earlier societies were organized in smaller groups, tribes, villages, where to a large extent "everybody knows everybody else"; in modern societies  you are regularly having expendable, effectively one-time interactions with strangers.  By this definition "modern" may go all the way back to say, parts of the classical world, but in the recent past, this pattern of interaction has become the norm in many societies.

This idea comes from Jared Diamond has written and [spoken on the topic of how traditional societies differ from modern industrial ones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7KKO50jv9E) ([and here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ceLuaf7low4)). 
Another point that he makes that strikes me is that we almost exclusively eat food that was grown by a stranger.